# SimpleMembershipProvider in Database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to use [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application but I could not find any useful information how I can store the user information in a MSSQL database?

Anybody can help me?

Comment: http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/ was the first link on google which uses seeding your database

Answer (score 1):

If you change the connection strings to point to the new database and just go to a SimpleMembership page(view) that uses the AccountController it should make the appropriate tables for you.

The AccountController should have the [InitializeSimpleMembership] filter applied - which is where the magic happens.